# What is the correct way to Take() X-number of records with LINQ but find out if there are more

Tags: c#, linq

Performance-wise, what is the best way to Take() records with LINQ-To-SQL, but at the same time find out if there is more? What I am currently doing is:

```
model.MyList = source.Take(11).ToList();

if (model.MyList.Count() > 10)
{
 model.HasMore = true;
 model.MyList= model.MyList.Take(10).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Take 12, iterate over 11 and add them to a new list, if iteration stops there you didn't have more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take `n + 1`, then count the received items. If their count is greater than `n`, then there are more records (at least one more).

Refering to your code, the following line `model.MyList= model.MyList.Take(10).ToList();` creates a new list. You can avoid doing this by simply removing the last item of the exisiting list: `model.MyList.RemoveAt(model.MyList.Count - 1)`. The longer the list, the higher the performance benefit.

```
model.MyList = source.Take(11).ToList();

if (model.MyList.Count > 10)
{
   model.HasMore = true;
   model.MyList.RemoveAt(model.MyList.Count - 1);
}
```

Comment: @HristoYankov What you're doing right now iterates over the entire enumerable from the start again. If you literally have tens of items and aren't doing it that frequently it probably doesn't matter, but this approach is more efficient.

Comment: Let me edit my post, I am doing "model.MyList = source.Take(11).ToList();" initially

Comment: @HristoYankov I believe so, the cost of getting `+1` item should be marginal.

Comment: @HristoYankov I updated the answer to address the code performance.

Comment: `.Count()` has [a optimization](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs.html#41ef9e39e54d0d0b) in it, if the object implments `ICollection` it just calls the `.Count` property on it, so while it is a little slower to call `.Count()` instead of `.Count` to do the overhead of the `source as ICollection;` check but it is not as bad as itterating over every item. **EDIT:** I guess you updated it as I was typing this.